# What are the correct steps to add Admob to Unity?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, admob

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start) leaves out really important steps.
Adding 'cocaopods' and 'Google Play Services'
They are just listed as prerequisites without even any links.

Another confusing thing is that, elsewhere I have seen that apparently I *don't* also need the [Unity Google Play Games Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks) for Admob to work. But in that case then why is 'Google Play Services' listed as a prerequisite on the official docs?

[image]